# MySQL query based on date

Tags: php, mysqli

I need a help with an sql statement. i have a featured user system based on 'likes', but once a user has been 'featured', they cannot be featured for the next 30 days. this has been written completely in php/mysql. any ideas?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: And where is said sql statement?

Comment: `select ... where (featured + interval 30 day) < now()`. mysql has extensive date/time functions, and you could have figured this out yourself: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, featuredID, featuredUser, firstname, lastname,DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
FROM featured 
WHERE featuredDateStart BETWEEN  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)ORDER BY count(favUser) desc
LIMIT 0, 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo code on the php side:

```
     $new_date = new DateTime;         
     $new_date->modify('30 day'); //set the next time they can be featured to 30 days in the future   

     while ($row = $qryResult ->fetch_assoc()) { //query table containing user, featured yes/no, date, etc
        $featured_date = new DateTime($row['featuredDate']);

     if ($featured date < $new_date) {
         echo $row['user'];
    }
  }
```